# What's up with version 2.3 of event drag

Tags: slickgrid

The Wiki page lists and links to version 2.2 of event drag library (threedubmedia.com).
However, the examples point to version 2.3, hosted in 6pac.github site.

What is this version about? Where does it come from? Can anybody give some information about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my repo. So for v2.3, we (@lfilho did these changes I believe) simply took 2.2 and updated it to be compatible with jQuery 2 and 3.

ThreeDub weren't involved, and the 2.2 version remains the latest release from them.